# Makefile not detecting changes to source file when running make

Tags: c, makefile, build, gnu-make

### Issue Description

I have a Makefile that is not recognizing when changes to the underlying source code are made. When I attempt a build I get the following message to the console: "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'."  My sense is that this probably has to do with a flawed understanding on my part regarding how to work with files in different directories. I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow but none seem to deal quite with this issue or the issue appears to result from other problems.

### Project Structure

**src**: the source code files live here.

**include**: header files live here.

**build**: object files live here.

**bin**: executables live here.

**test**: test code lives here.

**Makefile**: the make file.

### Makefiles

I have created a basic source file called main.c and placed it in src and implemented a simple make file as follows:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -DTESTABLE -Wall -std=c99 -g

all: bin/main

bin/main: build/main.o
build/main.o: src/main.c

clean:
    rm -f build/main.o
    rm -f bin/main
```

### Source File

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    printf( "Hi there. For real." );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
bin/main: build/main.o
build/main.o: src/main.c
```

tell make that to build `bin/main` it needs `build/main.o` and to build `build/main.o` it needs `src/main.c`, but you haven't actually told make *how* to build either `build/main.o` or `bin/main`.  You have to provide a recipe that make can use to actually do the build; maybe:

```
bin/main: build/main.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
build/main.o: src/main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```